# How to avoid overflow multiplication of very big numbers with recursive function (C# , D&C)

Tags: c#, recursion, overflow, divide-and-conquer, bignum

When the recursive function fires and returns the results up the way, it crashes because of data overflow. How can I use this D&C algorithm and avoid this problem?

```
static long long zarb(long a, long b, int n)
{
        Int64 w, x, y, z;
        int s;

        if (a == 0 || b == 0) 
           return 0;

        if (n <25)
            return a * b;
        else
        {
            s = n / 2;
            long p = power(2, s);
            w = a / p;
            x = a % p;
            y = b / p;
            z = b % p;
            return (zarb(w, y, n / 2) * power(2, 2 * s) + p * (zarb(w, z, n / 2) + zarb(x, y, n / 2)) + zarb(x, y, n / 2));
        }
}

static long power(int x, int y)
{
        long sum = 1;

        if (y == 0) 
           return 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= y; i++)
            sum = sum * x;

        return sum;
}
```

Comment: Overflow of long datatype? What is the exception you get? Is that `OverflowException` or `StackOverflowException` ?

Comment: So what exactly do you want the behavior to be? Preventing it from crashing is easy, but how do you want it handled?

Comment: `static long long` this is C#, not C. There is no `long long` here. And it is better if you don't mix `Int64` and `long`. They are the same thing, but it gives a bad feeling to the reader.

Comment: @xanatos Maybe because of long overflows in his case, OP tries to write it twice so that it becomes very long :p

Comment: power is technically wrong. x^0 == 1, not 0

Comment: guys my codes is true. when I multiply small numbers(long numbers) it works well but when I try too multiply big numbers(more than 50 numbers) it will crash with System.OverflowException. how should I avoid this error??? what can I use instead of long or int64 type??

Answer (score 2):

There is no real problem with your code, it works for a certain range of inputs.  If you need to be able to input values that will result in values out of the range in int64 try a different type.  System.Numerics is built into .NET and has a BigInteger type which claims "arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds."  It may take a while to run with those large valued inputs but it should be fine.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx